# ms mvvm toolkit: can't work out how to wire up ReplayCommand and canExecute

Tags: mvvm, uwp-xaml, model-binding

I have a simple model:

```
public sealed partial class ResultsModel : ObservableObject {

    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SaveCommand))]
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(ClearCommand))]
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Arrivals> _arrivals = new();

    public RelayCommand SaveCommand { get; private set; }
    public RelayCommand ClearCommand { get; private set; }

    internal ResultsModel() {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveRequest, CanSaveClear);
        ClearCommand = new RelayCommand(OnClear, CanSaveClear);
    }

    public bool CanSaveClear() {
        return _arrivals.Count > 0;
    }

    void OnClear() {
        _arrivals.Clear();
    }

    async void SaveRequest() {
    // save stuff
    }
}

// c#
DataContext = (model = new ResultsModel());
...
model.Arrivals.insert(0, thing); 

// The _arrivals are bound to an ItemsRepeater and appear in gui as //they're added
<ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{Binding Arrivals}">
<Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearCommand}"/>
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

I've bound buttons to the two Commands and they work ok, I just can't work how to get the canExecute code to run more than one time.

I was expecting that when items get added to the _arrivals collection (and they do) the canExecutes would be re-evaluated via the NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor attribute, but I'm obviously missing some glue somewhere because the button are always disabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code how you changed the ObservableCollection so we could try to reproduce your issue

Comment: ResultsModel model = new ResultsModel();
model.Arrivals.insert(0, thing);

The _arrivals are bound to an ItemsRepeater and appear normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't happen when you added an item to the `Arrivals`. But it will happen when you change the `Arrivals` by giving a new `ObservableCollection`. You could create a simple string property to test this behavior.

The reason for this behavior is that when the `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` Attribute is used, the `IRelayCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged` will be called when the setter of the property is called. In your scenario, that means only when the setter of the `Arrivals` property is called, this Attribute will call the `IRelayCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged`.

Comment: Thanks Roy, having to recreate the collection is a bit overkill for every insert, I've gotten around it now by adding an Add method to the model and doing the insert/add there and then calling `SaveCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged()` after.